# Wordlist Generator: Disaster after 2nd symbol

Tags: python, generator, brute-force, word-list

so this is a wordlist generator I built back when I started out with python (haven't done too much since then sadly) and yesterday while lying in bad I realized how I could finally fix my alphabetical generator, since I was having tons of problems with it. Now it is more or less finished, but there is just one thing, which is driving me insane, have a look:

```
# coding=utf8
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# vim: set fileencoding=utf8 :

# This is the number generator, the easy part

def number(length):  # Digit generator
    passw = 0
    length = 10 ** length
    for x in range(length):
        f.write(str(passw)),
        f.write("\n")
        passw += 1
    #   print passw -1


"""Now this is the alphabetical generator. I am using a while loop to iterate 
through the dictionary below. Tried it with a for loop first, but I ran into 
some problems."""


def alpha(combinations):
    durchgang = 0
    truepw = ""
    key = 0
    currentalpha = -1
    while key < combinations:               
        if key == 58:
            combinations -= 58
            currentalpha += 1
            if currentalpha == 58:
                currentalpha = 0
            key = 0
            truepw = letters[currentalpha]
            continue
        print truepw + letters[key]
        # print key
        key += 1

"""Now the problem I'm having, is that when I enter "2" as the length
of the password, everything works fine but as soon as I enter "3", I 
just get the same again as with "2". Now I know this is because I am 
overwriting "truepw" but I am just not sure how to add another "A" and then 
"B" etc. before "truepw". The same with a length of "4" etc. I just have a 
feeling I would need a million variables to which I always add the "new 
truepw"."""


f = open('wordlist.txt', 'w')
length = int(raw_input("Define length of password: "))
combinations = 58 ** length
letters = {
0:"A",
1:"B",
2:"C",
3:"D",
4:"E",
5:"F",
6:"G",
7:"H",
8:"I",
9:"J",
10:"K",
11:"L",
12:"M",
13:"N",
14:"O",
15:"P",
16:"Q",
17:"R",
18:"S",
19:"T",
20:"U",
21:"V",
22:"W",
23:"X",
24:"Y",
25:"Z",
26:"Ä",
27:"Ö",
28:"Ü",
29:"a",
30:"b",
31:"c",
32:"d",
33:"e",
34:"f",
35:"g",
36:"h",
37:"i",
38:"j",
39:"k",
40:"l",
41:"m",
42:"n",
43:"o",
44:"p",
45:"q",
46:"r",
47:"s",
48:"t",
49:"u",
50:"v",
51:"w",
52:"x",
53:"y",
54:"z",
55:"ä",
56:"ö",
57:"ü"
}

# number(length)
alpha(combinations)
```

Hope you guys can help me out somehow.

Comment: adding some expected output would help, I have no idea what the code is actually supposed to be doing

Comment: Well I really don't know how to describe it any better. If I enter "1" as pw length it should give me all letters from A-Z and a-z. I I enter "2" as pw length it should go through all 2704 combination possibilities, which it does. If I enter "3" it should go through all 140.608 combination possibilities, which it does not. It just outputs number "2" 52 times.

Comment: To elaborate on @Padraic, you may want to specify what your problem is.